# Angular 2 - Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'

Tags: angular, build, cli

Alguém sabe como solucionar ou direcionar em relação a esse erro quando gero um build com o Angular ?

Informações da versão utilizada do angular:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 5.2.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Print do erro ao usar o comando `ng build`

[image: Erro Screen]

Comment: O problema estava ocorrendo porque o aplicação já buildada está sendo testada em offline.
Quando o upload para o servidor da amazon foi realizada, a aplicação passou a funcionar.

Não sei bem se é essa a solução, mas funcionou aqui.